# How do I edit `lubuntu-rc.xml` in Lubuntu 21.04 to change the mouse binding of specific actions from Alt to Super?

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys

I want to change the mouse binding of the resize and drag actions for windows from using `Alt` to `Super`.

I'm supposed to edit the file `lubuntu-rc.xml`, but when I try to, it says I don't have permission to do anything with it. By the way, there's another file in the same folder named `lxqt-rc.xml` which I can edit, and that seems to contain the same information.

Either way, the sections I want to edit from `lubuntu-rc.xml` are the following:

```
<mousebind button="A-Right" action="Press">
  <action name="Focus"/>
  <action name="Raise"/>
  <action name="Unshade"/>
</mousebind>


<mousebind button="A-Right" action="Drag">
  <action name="Resize"/>
</mousebind>
```

However, even if I managed to edit the file, I don't know what I need to enter instead of "A-Right".

What should I do?

Comment: Elevate your permissions using `sudo`; the Lubuntu file is for the Lubuntu session (with Lubuntu's tweaks) where as the `lxqt` refers to the LXQt session (close to pure-upstream without Lubuntu tweaks) with the session being selected at login (at `sddm`).  You're asking about openbox configuration, so refer http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings

Comment: Oh, so I have to configure a different file. Alright, then so be it. Thank you for your comment! @guiverc

Comment: My detail was *vague* as I'm not sure what file you're exactly asking about (`lubuntu-rc.xml`); as you didn't provide any path, and I can't find it on a clean *focal* (20.04.3), clean *impish* (21.10) QA install, or my actual used systems (*impish* & *focal*). Are you trying to follow documentation somewhere (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows or equiv.  which you'll note contains a *deprecated* warning; that I put there). I'd appreciate knowing, as I can't find the `lubuntu-rc.xml` on a LXQt system, and if there is Lubuntu documentation that's wrong, I'd like to correct it.

Comment: User has re-posted an 'updated' request at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341294/help-changing-the-move-window-mouse-binding-in-lubuntu-21-04

Comment: As I describe in my updated request, the file I'm talking about is located in `~/.config/openbox`. However, it's empty.

With regards to the documentation, I'm not referring to any documentation; I'm just trying solutions I've found in older forum posts in this forum. @guiverc

Comment: Don't forget the stack in modern Lubuntu/LXQt differs to the older stack, so allow for it (if questions relate to LXDE).  I'd have asked your question on Lubuntu's discourse (so as to ensure a *dev* sees it), but I booted 4 boxes and on none did I have a `lubuntu-rc.xml` file so I have nothing to go on regards that file. My main, two QA-test installs & a secondary box do not have that file; and cannot see where it comes from in modern Lubuntu/LXQt.  This question was added to Lubuntu's support questions (unanswered) - https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/user_support_questions_%28unanswered%29/

Comment: @guiverc Let me see if I got you right: 1) I should make a post in a Lubuntu forum to increase the chances of getting help from a dev, 2) you can't find the `lubuntu-rc.xml` file anywhere, and 3) you've added my question to a list of questions related to Lubuntu. Is this correct?

Comment: Some details you need maybe found here https://phab.lubuntu.me/T59  (there's a list of the 3 places shortcuts can be placed; the list is key as items placed later in the stack override settings earlier ones; but I've not found it).  I don't know where you got lubuntu-rc.xml from as the only references I found for it were all LXDE thus don't apply (wrong desktop!)

Comment: That's very interesting. I'll give it a read. Thanks! @guiverc