# Help changing the move window mouse binding in Lubuntu 21.04

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys

*Note: This isn't a duplicate of [How do I edit `lubuntu-rc.xml` in Lubuntu 21.04 to change the mouse binding of specific actions from Alt to Super?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340875/how-do-i-edit-lubuntu-rc-xml-in-lubuntu-21-04-to-change-the-mouse-binding-of-s?noredirect=1#comment2291226_1340875*), nor does that post answer this one. In that post, I'm asking for help editing a file that turned out to be empty, while in this one I'm asking for help achieving what I wanted to get from editing the empty file.*

**Problem:**

I want to change the mouse bindings to move windows from using Alt to Super. To be clear, I'm referring to the `Alt+[mouse-1]` mouse binding.

**What I've tried:**

- Using the utilities, but I couldn't find anything on this
- Editing the `lxqt-rc.xml` and `rc.xml` files found in `~/.config/openbox`, then rebooting

**Additional information:**

- Here's what I've changed from the `*rc.xml` files:

```
    <mousebind button="W-Right" action="Press">
      <action name="Focus"/>
      <action name="Raise"/>
      <action name="Unshade"/>
    </mousebind>
   
   <mousebind button="W-Right" action="Drag">
      <action name="Resize"/>
    </mousebind>
```

- The `rc.xml` file is a copy I made of the file found in `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml`
- There's a `lubuntu-rc.xml` file in `~/.config/openbox`, but it's empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I edit \`lubuntu-rc.xml\` in Lubuntu 21.04 to change the mouse binding of specific actions from Alt to Super?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340875/how-do-i-edit-lubuntu-rc-xml-in-lubuntu-21-04-to-change-the-mouse-binding-of-s)

Comment: Please see my replies in the older post and the note I added at the top of this post. @guiverc

Answer (score 1):

I tested this in Lubuntu 20.10 (VirtualBox)

1. open `/home/<user>/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` for edit, if there is no file there make a copy from `etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` or `/etc/xdg/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml`
2. Go to Frame > Action:Move and change the binding from `A-Left` in:

   ```
   ...
   <context name="Frame">
     <mousebind button="A-Left" action="Press">
       <action name="Focus"/>
       <action name="Raise"/>
     </mousebind>
     <mousebind button="A-Left" action="Click">
       <action name="Unshade"/>
     </mousebind>
     <mousebind button="A-Left" action="Drag">
       <action name="Move"/>
     </mousebind>
     ...
   ```

   To: `W-Left`

   ```
   ...
   <context name="Frame">
     <mousebind button="A-Left" action="Press">
       <action name="Focus"/>
       <action name="Raise"/>
     </mousebind>
     <mousebind button="A-Left" action="Click">
       <action name="Unshade"/>
     </mousebind>
     <mousebind button="W-Left" action="Drag">
       <action name="Move"/>
     </mousebind>
     ...
   ```
3. Restart DM

   ```
     openbox --reconfigure
   ```

It works only with Right Super, Left Super is bind somewhere and trigger popup-menu (I didn't look at it yet).

Reference: [superuser.com/a/677838/](https://superuser.com/a/677838/98606)